# Error CS0560: Bad array declarator; Error CS0270: Array size cannot be specified in a variable declaration

Tags: c#, arrays, compiler-errors

When I try to run some code, I get the following errors:

```
/home/runner/Relational-Operators/Operators/Logical.cs(23,42): error CS0650: Bad array declarator: To declare a managed array the rank specifier precedes the variable's identifier. To declare a fixed size buffer field, use the fixed keyword before the field type. [/home/runner/Relational-Operators/main.csproj]
/home/runner/Relational-Operators/Operators/Logical.cs(23,43): error CS0270: Array size cannot be specified in a variable declaration (try initializing with a 'new' expression) [/home/runner/Relational-Operators/main.csproj]
```

This is the code block I am trying to run.

```
using System;

namespace Operators
{
    class Logical
    {
        public static void Run()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter two binary digits > ");
            int[] ints = new int[2]{Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read()), Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read())};
            bool[] bools = new bool[2];
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                switch (ints[i])
                {
                    case 0: bools[i] = false; break;
                    case 1: bools[i] = true;  break;
                    default:
                        throw new InvalidOperationException("Integer value is not valid");
                }
            }
            bool b1, b2 = bools[0], bools[1];
            if (b1 && b2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("true");
            }
            if (b1 || b2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("true");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("false");
            }
            if (!(b1 && b2))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("true");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am at a loss. I cannot find a way to fix the errors. From everything I've read anywhere so far, this code should be valid for C#.

What is causing these errors and how do I fix them?

Comment: I should denote: This class is part of a namespace imported into a `main.cs` with a `Main()` method in it. Just to avoid confusion.

Comment: this `bool b1, b2 = bools[0], bools[1];` should be `bool b1 = bools[0], b2 = bools[1];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way `b1` and `b2` are declared and assigned values in a single statement is causing this error.

You can change it so you assign the value to each variable directly like so:

```
bool b1 = bools[0], b2 = bools[1];
```

Or even unpack them as a tuple like so:

```
var (b1, b2) = (bools[0], bools[1]);
```